# powershell add key value to the json

Tags: json, powershell

I have the using the REST API to get the result, then I get the Json file, **ApiConnectionjson**:

```
$token = $(Token)
          
$header = @{authorization = "Bearer $token"}

$url = "https://management.azure.com/xxxx?api-version=2018-07-01-preview"
          
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header 
         
$ApiConnectionjson = $result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100

Write-Host "$ApiConnectionjson"
```

Now, I get the Json file via above powershell. No need to pay attention to the above code, it is not the key point.

The `ApiConnectionjson` like:

```
{
    "kind":  "V2",
    "properties":  {
                       "displayName":  "xxxx",
                       "authenticatedUser":  {
                                                 "name":  "xxx"
                                             },
                       "overallStatus":  "Connected",
                       "statuses":  [
                                        {
                                            "status":  "Connected"
                                        }
                                    ],
                       "connectionState":  "Enabled",
   ...
   ...
}
```

**Now I want add key value `"apiVersion": "2016-06-01",` in the first line to the json**, like:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "kind":  "V2",
    "properties":  {
                       "displayName":  "xxxx",
                       "authenticatedUser":  {
                                                 "name":  "xxx"
                                             },
                       "overallStatus":  "Connected",
                       "statuses":  [
                                        {
                                            "status":  "Connected"
                                        }
                                    ],
                       "connectionState":  "Enabled",
   ...
   ...
}
```

I have tried the method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285048/add-new-key-value-pairs-for-json-using-powershell): but my powershell does not support the method `pscustomobject`.

**Edit:**
My test code:

```
$ApiConnectionjson = $ApiConnectionjson | ConvertFrom-Json

$ApiConnectionjson += [pscustomobject] @{ apiVersion = '2016-06-01' }

$ApiConnectionjson  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Error message:

Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At D:\a_temp\azureclitaskscript1679387440203_inlinescript.ps1:17 char:1

Comment: please show your code and error msg

Comment: @FalcoAlexander, Although I don't find it useful, I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't have a `-AsHashTable` parameter which would make things easier (see: [`#19378` `Invoke-RestMethod` should have an `-AsHashTable` switch](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19378)). In other words, you will need to use the `Add-Member` cmdlet for this:

```
$Json = @'
{
    "kind":  "V2",
    "properties":  {
    "displayName":  "xxxx",
    "authenticatedUser": {
        "name": "xxx"
    },
    "overallStatus":  "Connected",
    "statuses": [
        {
            "status": "Connected"
        }
    ],
    "connectionState": "Enabled"
    }
}
'@
```

```
$Json |ConvertFrom-Json |
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "apiVersion" -Value "2016-06-01" -PassThru |
  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

```
{
  "kind": "V2",
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "xxxx",
    "authenticatedUser": {
      "name": "xxx"
    },
    "overallStatus": "Connected",
    "statuses": [
      {
        "status": "Connected"
      }
    ],
    "connectionState": "Enabled"
  },
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01"
}
```

---

In case *you want `"apiVersion": "2016-06-01"` to be added in the first line*, I would replace the concerned (top) object layer:

```
$Data = $Json |ConvertFrom-Json
$Data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    apiVersion = '2016-06-01'
    kind       = $Data.kind
    properties = $Data.properties
}
$Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

Or use the [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
$Json |ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object @{ n='apiVersion'; e={ '2016-06-01' } }, kind, properties |
    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the same result as you, it works for me. But for further optimization, I want to be added in the first line, what parameters should I modify

Comment: @Joy, see my update for: "*I want to be added in the first line*"

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code, this applies the new property using the `add-member` cmdlet prior to converting it to JSON as the object itself is easier to manipulate, then it uses the `select` cmdlet to force the position of the property to be the 1st value.

```
$versionNo = "x.x.x.x"

$token = $(Token)
      
$header = @{authorization = "Bearer $token"}

$url = "https://management.azure.com/xxxx?api-version=2018-07-01-preview"
      
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header 
     
$ApiConnectionjson = $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "apiVersion" -NotePropertyValue $versionNo | Select apiVersion, * | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100

Write-Host "$ApiConnectionjson"
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain the error as other answers are already given:

```
$jsonStr = @'
[{
    "kind":  "V2",
    "properties": {
        "displayName":  "xxxx",
        "authenticatedUser": {
            "name":  "xxx"
        },
        "overallStatus":  "Connected",
        "statuses":  [
        {
            "status":  "Connected"
        }
        ],
        "connectionState":  "Enabled"
        }
    }
]
'@

$json = $jsonStr | ConvertFrom-Json

# this now works because the insertion point at the root is now an array:
$json += [PSCustomObject] @{ apiVersion = 'V1.2.3' }
```

as long as it's an collection the `+=` is unknown.